# how can we send the ratings of rating bar from one activity to another activity in android

Tags: ratingbar

public View getView(final int position, View vi, ViewGroup arg2) {          View v = vi;            if(vi == null){                 viewHolder = new ViewHolder();              LayoutInflater linf=(LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                 v=linf.inflate(R.layout.feedback_custom_listview, null);                viewH

Comment: Is the code complete? Please format the code and add the necessary tags

Answer (score 0):

1. create an Intent
2. put the float rating into it
3. start new activity using this intent)